# Find Python Class Attributes In Shell

Tags: python, ruby, read-eval-print-loop, introspection

I am beginning to learn Python coming from Ruby on Rails.

I am wondering if there is a way to view attributes belonging to a class through the Python Shell?

In Ruby we simply enter the console and can type the name of the Class and its attributes are displayed.  Is there a way to do this in Python?

**Ruby Shell**

```
2.2.0 :001 > User
class User < ActiveRecord::Base {
                        :id => :integer,
                      :name => :string,
                     :email => :string,
        :encrypted_password => :string,
      :reset_password_token => :string,
    :reset_password_sent_at => :datetime,
       :remember_created_at => :datetime,
             :sign_in_count => :integer,
        :current_sign_in_at => :datetime,
           :last_sign_in_at => :datetime,
        :current_sign_in_ip => :string,
           :last_sign_in_ip => :string,
        :confirmation_token => :string,
              :confirmed_at => :datetime,
      :confirmation_sent_at => :datetime,
         :unconfirmed_email => :string,
                :created_at => :datetime,
                :updated_at => :datetime,
                      :role => :string,
                       :bio => :text,
                       :sex => :string,
                     :title => :string,
                :department => :string,
                  :keywords => :text,
                 :education => :text,
                    :skills => :text,
          :invitation_token => :string,
     :invitation_created_at => :datetime,
        :invitation_sent_at => :datetime,
    :invitation_accepted_at => :datetime,
          :invitation_limit => :integer,
             :invited_by_id => :integer,
           :invited_by_type => :string,
         :invitations_count => :integer
}
2.2.0 :002 >
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `dir()` function:

```
>>> print dir(str)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
```

It works on any object, including classes, builtins, and functions.

If you want the output formatted more like your ruby example:

```
In [169]: for attrib in dir(str):
    print "{0:18} =>  {1}".format(attrib, type(getattr(str, attrib)))
```

Output:

```
__add__            =>  <type 'wrapper_descriptor'>
__class__          =>  <type 'type'>
__contains__       =>  <type 'wrapper_descriptor'>
__delattr__        =>  <type 'wrapper_descriptor'>
__doc__            =>  <type 'str'>
__eq__             =>  <type 'wrapper_descriptor'>
__format__         =>  <type 'method_descriptor'>
__ge__             =>  <type 'wrapper_descriptor'>
__getattribute__   =>  <type 'wrapper_descriptor'>
...
```

Comment: is there a way to ONLY grab the attributes I created? like if a user was only made up of email it would return ONLY email? like my example above only returns attributes I have created

Comment: You can filter out the attribs that start with "__", but otherwise, `dir()` does not distinguish between inheritied attribs and user defined ones.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to print. You can simply just use dir().

Comment: I used print because I wanted the output all on one line -- I didn't want to take up 71 lines on the page.